# Spring-Boot Mysql: how to make a query to see if the database is empty?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring-boot and Jpa, I have a problem with a query.  I have to implement a method in which if there are no Users with a specific name, it returns me an error message while if there are, it returns me the one with the furthest insertion date.  Now I have done the code but I don't know how to insert the exception in case there is no name in the database.  I don't know how to put it in the method!  Below I enter the method I made

```
public UserUpdateEntity findFirstByName(String name) {
 
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<UserUpdateEntity> criteria = builder.createQuery(UserUpdateEntity.class);
        Root<UserUpdateEntity> root = criteria.from(UserUpdateEntity.class);
        criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("name"), name));
        criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("timestamp")));
        TypedQuery<UserUpdateEntity> query = em.createQuery(criteria).setMaxResults(1);
        return query.getSingleResult();

    }
```

Comment: do you mean that database still exists but does not contain any table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is misleading, this is how i have done it, when you use get single result it is bound to throw `NoResultException` in this case you should not `setMaxResults` and `getSingleResult` instead use `getResultList()` when its size is 1 you got the data present in the table otherwise something is fishy. Please follow my code below:

Entity class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_update_entity")
public class UserUpdateEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timestamp;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

CriteriQuery

```java
private UserUpdateEntity searchUserUpdateEntity(String name) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<UserUpdateEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(UserUpdateEntity.class);
        Root<UserUpdateEntity> from = criteriaQuery.from(UserUpdateEntity.class);
        criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get(UserUpdateEntity_.NAME), name));
        TypedQuery<UserUpdateEntity> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        // This line will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if result set is less than 1
        UserUpdateEntity result = typedQuery.getResultList().get(0);
        return result;
    }
```

Test to check the logic

```java
@Test
    void testUserExists() {
        UserUpdateEntity userUpdateEntity = new UserUpdateEntity();
        userUpdateEntity.setName("random-user");
        userUpdateEntity.setTimestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        entityManager.persist(userUpdateEntity);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(userUpdateEntity.getId());
        UserUpdateEntity searched = searchUserUpdateEntity(userUpdateEntity.getName());

        Assertions.assertSame(searched, userUpdateEntity);

        try {
            searched = searchUserUpdateEntity("asdada");
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Assertions.assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```